# List values are changing after passed into function

Tags: python, python-2.7

The idea was to have static values for the list 'a', but its contents seems to be changing once this list pass through the operation of a function.

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
u = []

def f(a1, num):
    x = []
    n = len(a1)
    for i in range(n):
        a1[i] = a1[i] + num
        x.append(0)
    for i in range(n):
        x[i] = x[i] + a1[i]
    #a1 = a2
    return x

u = f(a, 10)
print "u = ", u 
print "a = " ,a 

u = f(a, 100)
print "u = ", u 
print "a = " ,a
```

The output is:

```
u =  [11, 13, 15] 
a =  [11, 13, 15]  
u =  [111, 113, 115]  
a =  [111, 113, 115]
```

I've been trying to create a copy of the list and hope to mantain the original values, but still nothing.

Any ideas are really appreciated
:)

Comment: `u = f(a.copy(), 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried copying the list like this?

```
u = f(a[:], 10)
```

Alternatively, `x[i]` always starts at zero, so I think you can simplify

```
def f(a1, num):
    return [a + num for a in a1]
```

Comment: Now it's working (that simplification goes beyond my rookie level) . Thnx, dude :)

Comment: It's called list comprehension, but basically, you only needed to assign `x[i] = a[i] +num `, never changing the input parameters

Answer (score 0):

A list in Python is an object, so it is passed by reference into `f()`.  Anything you do to modify `a1` inside of function will operate on the original list object.

Your code assigns to an element of `a1` directly at the line:

```
        a1[i] = a1[i] + num
```

You might consider assigning in to `x` or to a temporary variable here, rather than assigning back to `a1`.